# DevIL - how do I save filters to my GL_QUADS texture?

Tags: opengl

I used DevIL to load in my images. DevIL has some nice filter functions, such as alienify(), contrast(), etc. there is a problem though.

These filters showed fine when I drew the pixels to the color buffer. When I started using geometry, such as glBegin(GL_QUADS), the original texture shows, but the filter does not. How can I update the texture with iluAlienify()?

Comment: What's your code for applying filter and sending result to GL?

Comment: That could be the problem. With glDrawPixels(), I just drew the current pointer to the color buffer. With textures, is there a different function to update the memory?

Comment: Ah, found it: glTexSubImage2D​(). Source: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes

Comment: Yes, but why do you wanted to update it in first place? Why not apply filter first and only then create GL texture?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use glTexSubImage2D​() when a texture is already existing.

For example,

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, m_handle);   
iluAlienify();    // filters a texture
glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB, 0, 0, 0, m_width, m_height, m_imageFormat, m_imageType, ilGetData());
```